# Gray lines appearing around expanded vector shapes when exporting PDF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, pdf

So I vectorized some images and expanded them, but when I export them as PDFs they have these gray lines around them. How can I remove them? (But without rasterizing; rasterizing it makes the colors very subtly streak/band when viewing the pdf online). I've already tried turning off anti-aliasing, but it does nothing. The lines look like this on the pdf:

[image]

Comment: You say this happens when you export to PDF. Aren't the lines visible in Illustrator? Do the paths have *stroke* applied or are they gray lines *filled* paths? Why are you using a PDF to show something online?

Comment: @Wolff its a PDF because it's a newsletter/educational resource type thing. There's type on it and all that. The lines aren't visible in illustrator, and they don't have strokes applied. What are filled paths?

Comment: OK, seems strange. By "filled paths" I simply mean that just like you have blue, orange, yellow and gray paths, the gray lines could be paths between your colored paths (remember I haven't seen your file - strange things can happen when you vectorize images). But since you can't see them in Illustrator I doubt that's what is happening.

Comment: Does the PDF look fine in Acrobat?

Comment: I don't really use acrobat. Should I try opening it up there?

Comment: This will only be for online viewing btw

Comment: I understand that it's only for online viewing, but I'm just trying to help narrow down, what the problem could be. Acrobat is a really solid viewer. The PDF viewers in web browsers have some problems.

Comment: Nvm I fixed it by offsetting the path by a very small amount with bevel (0.001 whatever units its set to). Thank for your help though!